# How can i bulk export Products like sku, products name, request path and Target path

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite, importexport, product-urls

I need to **How can i bulk export Products like sku, products name, request path and Target path**, 
is there any way I can bulk download request path and target path url.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a magento feature to export or you are free to add a custom php script for this?

Comment: just i need to export request and target path url ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can export the id, sku, name and request & target paths with this sql:

```
select e.entity_id, e.sku, ev.value as name,  u.request_path, u.target_path 
from catalog_product_entity e 
inner join catalog_product_entity_varchar ev on ev.entity_id = e.entity_id and ev.attribute_id = 
    (select attribute_id from eav_attribute a inner join eav_entity_type et on et.entity_type_id = a.entity_type_id where a.attribute_code = 'name' and et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product') 
inner join core_url_rewrite u on u.id_path = concat('product/', e.entity_id) and u.is_system=1 and options is null;
```

you can either run this query from the command line as
    mysql -E "paste your query here" > outfile.tsv
generating a tab-separated file

or from phpmyadmin, which allows exporting the current result set quite easily.

ultimately you can use 
    INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/outfile.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

if you need more product attributes, you would need a script, since the sql would become very difficult to read

Comment: also, if you need all rewrites (custom or system), just remove the "u.is_system = 1 and options is null" part from the query

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php    
require_once('app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app();

    $data=Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->getCollection();

    $fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w+');
    $csvHeader = array('request_psth',"target_path");
    fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,",");
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        fputcsv($fp, array($row->getData('request_path'),$row->getData('target_path')), ",");
    }
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

use this script it will generate csv in root.

Comment: just i past this code in root folder and run ?? right ??

Comment: how can i run this script

Comment: ya u create test.php file in root and run this file it will generate csv file in root

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/41q3Um8.png

Comment: does right ?....

Comment: my output is...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/jQGt04n.png

Comment: u write code in <?php ?> section?

Comment: you createa one test.php file in magento root directory and peste this code that i give

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45747/discussion-between-jigs-parmar-and-jeeva-rathinam).

Comment: only working in localhost, not working in hosting site.

Answer (score 1):

### Via phpMyAdmin

Well, you could simply do it via phpMyAdmin.

Go to the `core_url_rewrite` table and click the export tab.

Then choose CSV in the format dropdown.

Click Export, you're done.

### Via MySQL command line

```
SELECT request_path,target_path
FROM core_url_rewrite
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/rewrites.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Just replace `/tmp/rewrites.csv` with the path that fits your needs

Comment: Your first option okay, but how can i match by sku, Actually i need sku, request path, and target path, so only i can match all products in my store from other site.